# Order of rows in matrix excluding zero values in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix say "mat" containing zero values. For example:

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    2    5    1    4    3
 [2,]    0    0    2    4    3
 [3,]    2    5    0    3    1
 [4,]    4    5    2    3    1
 [5,]    1    5    2    3    4
 [6,]    2    5    1    4    3
 [7,]    0    0    0    5    1
 [8,]    1    5    4    2    3
 [9,]    3    5    1    0    2
[10,]    2    5    4    1    3
```

I'd like to have the order of indices of matrix' rows excluding zero values. However, zero values of each row should stay in the resulted matrix but at the end. For instance, for the given "mat" matrix, the result should be like so:

```
> res
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    3    1    5    4    2
 [2,]    3    5    4    0    0
 [3,]    5    1    4    2    0
 [4,]    5    3    4    1    2
 [5,]    1    3    4    5    2
 [6,]    3    1    5    4    2
 [7,]    5    4    0    0    0
 [8,]    1    4    5    3    2
 [9,]    3    5    1    2    0
[10,]    4    1    5    3    2
```

I came up with the following code:

```
if (sum(mat==0)>0){ # mat contains zeros
        mat[which(mat==0, arr.ind = TRUE)]=NA
        l=apply(mat, 1, function(x) order(x, na.last = NA))
        mat=t(sapply(l, '[', 1:max(sapply(l, length))))
        mat[which(is.na(mat), arr.ind = TRUE)]=0
        return(mat)
    }
```

Do you guys have better idea or better algorithm for doing so in R? thanks

Test data:

```
mat <- structure(c(2, 0, 2, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
0, 5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 0, 1, 
3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3), .Dim = c(10L, 5L))
```

Comment: can you dput() the matrix `mat` so we can test?

Comment: Sure, here it is:
'structure(c(2, 0, 2, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 
5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 
0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3), .Dim = c(10L, 5L))'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that the order you provided in `res` is the order including the zeros. I don't know if that's what you meant to do (it doesn't fit your problem description), but in case you want to do that, you could do:

```
res <- apply(mat,1,function(i){
   out <- order(i)
   iszero <- i == 0
   c(out[!iszero[out]], i[iszero])
 })
 res <- t(res)

> res
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    3    1    5    4    2
 [2,]    3    5    4    0    0
 [3,]    5    1    4    2    0
 [4,]    5    3    4    1    2
 [5,]    1    3    4    5    2
 [6,]    3    1    5    4    2
 [7,]    5    4    0    0    0
 [8,]    1    4    5    3    2
 [9,]    3    5    1    2    0
[10,]    4    1    5    3    2
```

which gives you the exact `res` you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the second row of res should be"
[2,]    3    5    4    0    0

Comment: @m0h3n see my edit, and that is not what you said. You wanted the order with the zeros excluded. Now you have both.

Comment: Thanks but your solution fails for the following matrix:
`mat <- structure(c(0, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 5, 1, 0, 
4, 4, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 5, 
0, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2), .Dim = c(10L, 5L))`

Comment: thanks. now we are on the same boat :) I examined your solution vs. mine for relatively large matrices (i.e. `50000*5`), your solution is approximately 5 times faster than that of I proposed. already voted up!